# Can I use Google Assistant alongside another assist app?

Tags: google-assistant

I already have an assist app setup which needs access to the text on my screen.

Currently, when I open Google Assistant through its icon on my homescreen, I get a screen telling me "The Google app isn't your default assist app" ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mipoY.png))

I don't want to use Google Assistant to interact with what's on my screen, rather I just want to use it as a voice assistant. I could just use the default "Google" app which has features for voice search, but "Google Assistant" does that AND has the ability to [integrate nicely](https://ifttt.com/services/google_assistant) with other apps using IFTTT, which is something I want to set-up.

Is there a way to use Google Assistant integrations from the regular google app, to use Google Assistant can be used alongside another assist app?